# Not casting properly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, casting, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.makegameswith.us/gamernews/369/build-your-own-flappy-bird-with-spritebuilder-and). And I keep getting this casting error. I've imported the Obstacle.h file in the shown class (MainScene.m). I have no idea what I'm doing wrong

```
 - (void)spawnNewObstacle {
     CCNode *previousObstacle = [_obstacles lastObject];
     CGFloat previousObstacleXPosition = previousObstacle.position.x;

     if (!previousObstacle) {
         // this is the first obstacle
         previousObstacleXPosition = firstObstaclePosition;
     }

     Obstacle *obstacle = (Obstacle *)[CCBReader load:@"Obstacle"];
     obstacle.position = ccp(previousObstacleXPosition + distanceBetweenObstacles, 0);
     [obstacle setUpRandomPosition];
     [_physicsNode addChild:obstacle];
     [_obstacles addObject:obstacle];
 }
```

**Error:**

```
-[CCNode setUpRandomPosition]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9a88a30
2014-04-20 10:51:28.046 FlappyFlyl[2104:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CCNode setUpRandomPosition]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9a88a30'
```

Comment: What makes you think that casting changes the class of an object??  All it does is tell the compiler to consider the type to be the one specified.

Comment: afaik obstacle is the first child of the node returned by ccbreader load

Comment: Sorry, I haven't programmed in a while and I've forgotten a lot of these concepts. What would you suggest I do to fix it? The example runs fine with the same code

Comment: write a correct CCNode class that has the code you expect it to have

Comment: @LearnCocos2D that is only the case for `loadAsScene`. A regular `load` should return the SpriteBuilder root node.

Answer (score 1):

Likely you didn't set the custom class of your root node in "Obstacle.ccb" in SpriteBuilder correctly. That's why your "Obstacle.ccb" root node is a `CCNode` and not an `Obstacle` object.

Answer (score 0):

The `obstacle` variable does not hold an object of type `Obstacle`. Instead it holds an object of type `CCNode`. `CCNode` does not have a method named `-setUpRandomPosition`, so you get a runtime error. In Objective-C, casting is a no-op. It doesn't do anything except helping the reader of your code see the intent of the person who wrote the code.

In this regard Objective-C differs from languages like C++ or Java. Objective-C has an object system that is similar to the programming language "Smalltalk".